# How to handle too many aggregation operation?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In my requirement, reading the table from hive (Size - around 1 TB) I have to do too many aggregation operation mostly avg & sum.
I tried following code.its running for long time .Is there another way to optimize or efficient wasy of handling multiple agg operatin

```
finalDF.groupBy($"Dseq", $"FmNum", $"yrs",$"mnt",$"FromDnsty")
   .agg(count($"Dseq"),avg($"Emp"),avg($"Ntw"),avg($"Age"),avg($"DAll"),avg($"PAll"),avg($"DSum"),avg($"dol"),
     avg($"neg"),avg($"Rd"),avg("savg"),avg("slavg"),avg($"dex"),avg("cur"),avg($"Nexp"), avg($"NExpp"),avg($"Psat"),
     avg($"Pexps"),avg($"Pxn"),avg($"Pn"),avg($"AP3"),avg($"APd"),avg($"RInd"),avg($"CP"),avg($"CScr"),
     avg($"Fspct7p1"), avg($"Fspts7p1"),avg($"TlpScore"),avg($"Ordrs"),avg($"Drs"),
     avg("Lns"),avg("Judg"),avg("ds"),
     avg("ob"),sum("Ss"),sum("dol"),sum("liens"),sum("pct"),
     sum("jud"),sum("sljd"),sum("pNB"),avg("pctt"),sum($"Dolneg"),sum("Ls"),sum("sl"),sum($"PA"),sum($"DS"),
     sum($"DA"),sum("dcur"),sum($"sat"),sum($"Pes"),sum($"Pn"),sum($"Pn"),sum($"Dlo"),sum($"Dol"),sum("pdol"),sum("pct"),sum("judg"))
```

Note - I am using Spark Scala

Comment: do you want to apply avg and sum to all columns?

Comment: based on certain condition i have added few columns on the table .I want to do avg and sum.kind of  applying to all coulmns